# How is rolling back transaction related to LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, transactions

The question is solely about rolling back the changes, not commiting.

Let's say I fetch some data, I change them, I submit changes (optional step) and I roll back transaction. Wherever you look every author writes, this cancels the changes.

But I found out that is half true -- LINQ DataContext will keep the changed data! I tested this using TransactionScope and DataContext.Transaction. In both cases I got the same behaviour.

A workaround would be to recreate DataContext after roll back (however this leads to other problems like caching data and handling nested transactions) or manually discarding the changes in DataContext. Nevertheless those are just workarounds.

#### Questions

So what am I missing? Is LINQ to SQL not suited for transactions? How to use transactions so they would **REALLY** roll back changes?

#### Example

```
                MyTable record = null;

                db.Connection.Open();
                using (db.Transaction = db.Connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                        record = db.MyTable.First();
                        record.BoolField = !record.BoolField; // changed
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                        db.Transaction.Rollback();
                }
```

Comment: Can you add sample code please?

Comment: I think what you're saying is that you want to rollback the state of the data context as well as rolling back any changes made to the database when you rollback the transaction.  Is that right?

Comment: "rolling back", not "rollbacking".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A data-context should be considered as a unit-of-work. How *granular* you make that is up to you - it could be a page request, or a single operation; but - if you get an exception (or pretty much anything unexpected) - ***stop***; abandon the data-context and rollback. After a rollback, your data-context is going to be confused, so just *don't keep it*.

Additionally; don't keep a data-context for longer than necessary. It is not intended as an app-long data cache.

Comment: Thank you, but it is no-go. It simply means you cannot cache any data (I described this issue when asking).

Comment: @macias - please understand: a data-context is **not your cache**. If you want a cache... *use a cache*... over-extending the lifetime of a data-context will lead to nothing but pain. I use LINQ-to-SQL, and I cache data excessively - I just don't try to force data-context into doing it, because (and I might have said this): ***data-context is not your cache***.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Marc, did I somewhere write that I use DC cache? No. So why do you assume I do it? I cache data (in List<>) but I cannot mix cached data and newly created DC together, and this is the point of caching data.

Comment: @macias - don't confuse storing temporary copies of persisted data elsewhere with caching. Caching is more than keeping a temporary copy; caching implies synchronization with the underlying permanent store. LINQ to SQL is a persistence mechanism (track and save changes), not a synchronization mechanism -- though it will update DB-generated fields on a save.  To get a true cache you have to have both the temporary local storage and add synchronization on failure --either by reverting to the old, in-memory object or re-fetching.  You can use L2S for that but it won't do it for you automatically.

Comment: ... I'm not saying that the previous comment completely describes caching, merely describing a key component that your list-based solution still lacks.  For one thing, you'd typically need a way to prune relatively "old" data to keep the size of the cache small, tune the size to keep it performant, etc.

Comment: @macias - "Marc, did I somewhere write that I use DC cache? No." - erm, maybe I misinterpreted your previous comment - but you surely said that the idea of abandoning the data-context was no-go because "t simply means you cannot cache any data"... so - if I read that wrong, what *did* you mean?

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be asking for is an in-memory cache of the database (or some part of it) rather than a lightweight ORM. I would say that LINQ to SQL is just fine for transactions and as a lightweight ORM, but not so good to use out of the box as a database cache.  The data context functions best, in my opinion, using the Unit of Work pattern.  Create the context for a particular task, perform the task, then dispose of the context.  If the task happens to include a failed transaction, then you need to figure out how to respond to the failure.  This could be by either correcting the errors and retrying with the existing context or, as in a web context, passing back the attempted changes to the user, then trying again with a new context when the data is resubmitted.

Comment: What you are saying between the lines, is if I want caching the data, the best option would be to ditch LINQ to SQL. Correct?

Comment: @macias - no, I'm saying that you would need something on top of LINQ to SQL, something additional.  In MVC, it comes in the form of ModelState -- which is used to regenerate form inputs when persisting the changes fails.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) stale datacontext

What you observe is commonly refered to as a 'stale' datacontext. The entities in the datacontext do not notice your rollbak. You would get simular behaviour if you would execute a stored procedure after your submitchanges. That will also not be noticed by the datacontext. However, your transactions will be rolled back in the DB! (and likewise the stored procedure will be executed)

2) about transactions

There is no need to manage the transaction. Linq2Sql already creates a transaction for you in the Submitchanges.
If you really want to manage the transactions (e.g. over multiple datacontexts or a stored procedure combined with some linq2sql, wrap the whole thing in a TransactionScope. Call transaction.Complete() at the point where you want to commit.

Comment: 2) there is a need fo transactions, several SubmitChanges won't be rolled back by magic, I have to group them as one logic operation. TransactionScope -- it is not a magic either (I wrote about in question), the behaviour is exactly the same, data in memory are not refreshed.

Comment: That is because of the stale datacontext. The transactions are roled back, if you do not believe it check your database. Just your datacontext does not notice it because it is "going behind the back" of the datacontext so to speak. Try for example to do an update through the datacontext and after that update the same entity with a stored procedure - the datacontext will not notice. Therefore you need to keep the lifecycle of your datacontext a short as possible. This by design. Like it or not but there is nothing to do about it.