# How to use only IDs for foreign table instead of full objects on insert/update?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

My program is more complex, but basically the problem is like this -- there is table Customer and table City. In Customor I have field cityId and foreign key for it.

Now I can write such code

```
customer.cityIdCity = myCity;
```

or

```
customer.cityId = 7;
```

The issue is I cannot use the first form, because cities are cached, and in such case the data would be "hijacked" by current data context (and exception would occur), so I prefer using the second form. However when I submit changes for customer I get exception about inconsistency within data -- which is honestly speaking true -- cityId is 7, but cityIdCity is null.

**The question is** -- for the second form, how to force LINQ to focus on id (and execute simple insert with id used), and accept missing object.

## Edits

### 1

The field cityId is just an int (as in table), but sqlmetal also created another property for mapping class cityIdCity which is reference to City class (from table City).

Internally it looks like this:

```
    private EntityRef<City> _cityIdCity;
```

There is also a long property cityIdCity which sets the above field and handles event triggering for changing and changed state of the field.

And regular field (int) is defined like this:

```
    private System.Nullable<int> _cityId;
```

plus analogous property.

### 2

I found out it is due to fetching data. Once data are loaded (city object for customer in this case), Linq To SQL assumes it is **fixed**, i.e. id and city reference have to be in sync. If you don't read them before changing them it is ok, because L2S sets new values but also fetches new data from DB on fly.

And I have to read city of customer before I change it.

### 3

The steps are as follows:

1. find in DB a customer
2. it does not exist? --> create record
3. is the city of customer the same as the incoming data (city)? if yes, go to step (8)
4. check in cache if we have appropriate city, if yes go to (7)
5. create city record
6. save city
7. bind city and customer
8. save customer

So in (3) there is read of city field of customer, and in (7) there is either complain about using data from another context or fields out of sync (case when data are changed).

For comparison I tested several cases using Entity Framework and it behaves more straightforward, i.e. there are no problems in both approaches (when changing referenced field with whole object or just id).

### 4

This is simplified code, but shows the problem.

```
using (var Db = new L2S.DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var customer = Db.Customers.Single(it => it.cust_Id==2);
    customer.Name = "New name";
    Console.WriteLine(customer.City.city_Name); // loading city from DB
    // cannot change, because we would be out of sync with referenced object
    customer.city_Id = 57834; 
                            
    Db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

### 5 -- thin vs. fat data context

Using the same example as Pleun. This is fat DC:

```
using (var Db = new L2S.DataClasses1DataContext())
{    
   ...
   customer.City = Db.Cities.Single (i=> i.id =   57834 ); 
   Db.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

because as you can see customer uses the same DC as the cities (cities are cached!). This is wrong, because every malformed data from customer will creep to DC (cache). So an error from an hour ago, will also be present now.

This is thin DC:

```
var city = CacheDb.Cities.Single (i=> i.id =   57834 ); 

...

using (var Db = new L2S.DataClasses1DataContext())
{    
   ...
   customer.City = city; 
   Db.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

However this won't work because L2S does not allow sharing entities between DC (in typical case between cache and working -- updating -- DC).

Comment: I do not understand the difference between CityId and cityIdCity. Can you show your complete table structure? In general the second approach should work fine with Linq-to-sql if cityId is a foreign key

Comment: @Pleun, I added explanation about them -- those two are standard SQLMetal "outputs". In my case it never worked -- L2S on one hand sees id, and on the second hand it sees null value for City object.

Comment: Well, In general in Linq2sql you should be able to do either Customer.citytablename = city or customer.cityid = 6 (and do not touch the citytablename). Both ways will work. It seems to me your problem is somewhere else. If you do a straight insert with only the required fields hardocded it also fails?

Comment: @Pleun, sorry about insert, I made so many tests, that just for safety let's generalize "insert/update". Just "customer.cityid = 6" will work in all scenarious, but if you for example do a Console.WriteLine of cityid and it is not 6, then assignment of 6 will fail.

Comment: @macias : Try disabling  trackchanges on the context and see if it works.

Comment: @Furqan, you mean ObjectTrackingEnabled=false? I cannot do this, because in such case I couldn't access referenced data (they would be null).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
using (var Db = new L2S.DataClasses1DataContext())
{    
 ...
 // leave out customer.city_Id = 57834;  but replace with
 customer.City = Db.Cities.Single (i=> i.id =   57834 ); 
 Db.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

Comment: This is not possible. Note you are using **the same** data context. It would mean that you have one, single, fat data context which tracks all data. With such approach you would run into problems with transactions which are (in reality) unsolvable. DC lifetime should be per each task. In my case -- one DC per cache, the second for processing customers.

Comment: I do not agree with you. Of course I am using the same datacontext. That is in my opinion the whole idea of Linq-to-sql. You should have on DC-class per database and one DC-instance per unit-of-work. I am managing millions of transactions like this and never a problem.

Comment: Unit of work is cache, and in your code you are using the same **INSTANCE** of DC which is wrong; so you should use another instance. And it is not possible to fetch object from cache (using its own DC instance) in L2S. Transactions and DC -- data context does not refresh its state if transaction fails, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977452/how-is-rolling-back-transaction-related-to-linq-to-sql

Comment: That's exacly why you have to keep the lifetime of DC as short as possible, in other words one per unit of work. This is also the general anwer in the link you provide. If you keep them too long the DC will go stale.

Comment: you contradict yourself. You are telling me about short lifetime (I agree) and yet you suggest that I should do the opposite -- see your example, reusing the same DC for cache **AND** for "normal" work. See edit no. 5.